# wxPython Application.DoEvents() equivalent?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is there an Application.DoEvents() equivalent in wxPython?

I am creating a form, then doing a slow I/O event, and the form is only partially drawn until the event finishes. I'd like to have the form fully drawn before the I/O starts.

I've tried `self.Refresh()`, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wx.Yield`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_appinifunctions.html#wxyield) or [`wx.SafeYield`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_appinifunctions.html#wxsafeyield)

Although you should really use a separate thread to do the I/O and use [`wx.CallAfter`](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter) to post updates to the GUI thread.

I usually use a pattern like this:

```
def start_work(self):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.do_work, args=(args, go, here))
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()
def do_work(self, args, go, here):
    # do work here
    # wx.CallAfter will call the specified function on the GUI thread
    # and it's safe to call from a separate thread
    wx.CallAfter(self.work_completed, result, args, here)
def work_completed(self, result, args, here):
    # use result args to update GUI controls here
    self.text.SetLabel(result)
```

You would call `start_work` from the GUI, for example on an `EVT_BUTTON` event to start the work.  `do_work` is run on a separate thread but it cannot do anything GUI related because that has to be done on the GUI thread.  So you use `wx.CallAfter` to run a function on the GUI thread, and you can pass it arguments from the work thread.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'll look into doing the IO on a separate thread.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, there is no documentation that explains how to work properly with IO in wxpython. Your example explain it very nicely.